# Wordpress Elementor Sticky Header - Icon Change Color

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to make my header on wordpress sticky - it changes from transparent to white background

On the transparent part - the icons are white

But when i scroll down - the white background kicks in and I am not able to change the color to black

Right now I am uploaded my own SVG to the icon

I managed to change color of my menu using

```
.elementor-sticky--effects a{color:#000!important;}
```

Website: https://weddingculturefilms.towaiji.com/

I am unable to find a way to change the icons color - please and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you...

```
.elementor-sticky--effects .elementor-icon svg g {
    fill: green;
}
```